# Timer once a minute on the minute

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I can't get the timer to fire once a minute on the minue, 1:00, 1:01, 1:02 etc. Instead, when the timer executes drifts by a couple of seconds each iteration

```
   internal void StartTimer()
    {
        DateTime nowEastern = CalendarEntity.Calendar.GetEasternTime();

        int secondsInterval = 5;

        double additionalSeconds = secondsInterval - nowEastern.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds % secondsInterval;
        if (additionalSeconds == 0)
        {
            additionalSeconds = 1;
        }
        var nearestOnOneMinutes = new DateTime(
            nowEastern.Year,
            nowEastern.Month,
            nowEastern.Day,
            nowEastern.Hour,
            nowEastern.Minute,
            nowEastern.Second
        ).AddSeconds(additionalSeconds);

        TimeSpan timeToStart = nearestOnOneMinutes.Subtract(nowEastern);
        TimeSpan tolerance = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        if (timeToStart < tolerance)
        {
            timeToStart = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        timer_onem = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimedEvent, null,
                                    (int)timeToStart.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object o)
    {
        var minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        var second = DateTime.Now.Second;
        if (minute != lastMinute && second % 60 < 2)
        {
            lastMinute = minute;
            CodeToExecute();
        }
    }

    static void CodeToExecute()
    {
        double tms = 60000;

        // code here
        int wait = 60 - System.DateTime.Now.Second;

        timer_onem.Change(Convert.ToInt64(tms) - wait, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

I changed the interval so that it fires once a second and then check that the minute has changed. Still drifts

```
    timer_onem = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimedEvent, null,
                                    (int)timeToStart.TotalMilliseconds, 1000);

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object o)
    {
        var minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;

        if (minute != lastMinute)
        {
            lastMinute = minute;
            CodeToExecute();
        }
    }

    private static void CodeToExecute()
    {
        if (bGenerate)
        {
            double tms = 1000;
            // code
            timer_onem.Change(Convert.ToInt64(tms), 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the code you execute creating a lot of workload? If so you should probably move it to a background worker..

Comment: nah totally passive code.

Answer (score 3):

A `Timer` is only **guaranteed to be no faster** than `Interval`.

So you need to call it, say every second and check for the full minute.

For even better precision you would have to check every 1/2 second or better.

It is a basic rule of information theory that says that to measure with a given resolution (1 second in your case) you need to sample with better than twice that resolution. Hence to measure 20kHz you need a smpling rate better than 2x20kHz, say 44.1kHz. (Recognize the numbers?)

If you don't want to call it so **often** for simply getting **one** precise point in time, you could write a little more involved code that on each `Tick` resets the `Timer.Interval` to a little **under half** of the remaining time until the next full minute until it is under say  500ms..

There are rather complex things going on in your code wrt to setting up the expected time, though; do make sure they are not the real problem. There should **not** be a **growing** drift from the timer's lack of precision, unless you '**collect**' the errors..

Comment: See Edit 1. Doesn't seem to help to increase the frequency of timed events.

Comment: Are you saying that in order for me to get something to execute on a integer-minute boundary with +/-1 once second drift (or 60000 milliseconds), I have to have a timer fire once every 500 milliseconds? That seems absurd. So 1:01:01, 1:02:02, 1:03:02, 1:04:01 is ok, But I get 1:01:02, 1:02:04, 1:03:06, etc. Increasing monotonically on the seconds.

Comment: Well it is a basic rule of information theory and says that to measure with a given resolution you need to sample with better than twice that resolution. Hence to measure 20kHz you need better than 2x20kHz, say 44kHz. (Recognize the numbers?) Of course this is wasteful if you only need to measure one point in time; see my last paragraph for an optimized but still simple algorithm.

Comment: - Not sure though if not maybe the other things in your code might be the culprits..In fact the growth of the drift __must__ have a different cause. I suggest you log out the expected times and see if they look sound..