# C#: use Timer in smart way

Tags: c#, timer

Now I understand it's two possible cases to use Timer:

1. do some action with specified interval, it's quite easy.
2. another usage (and more interesting for me): for instance we have array of times `[11.24, 15.06, 17.47]` (and it's possible to add more times there). We need to execute some operation at this moments. It looks like here I need timer with 1 minute interval to compare current hours and minutes with all items from array. And in case of **TRUE** execute action. **But** what if this operation takes 2 minutes for instance? In this case it's possible to miss some item from array. I think solution here is to separate logic for queueing (timer with 1 min interval to check time and add to queue) and logic for listening queue and execute action.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you are writing a scheduler. I would suggest using Quartz.NET - it's a really good scheduling library, and the [SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html) should easily meet your needs.

Comment: Will the array change once you've started the timer?

Comment: I do not think checking array values with current time will take too much time, unless you have few hundreds of thousands array length. Even in that case, you may divide the array hourly; you can create separate array for every hour and check that array only in that hour.

Comment: @Bob after timer is started array is immutable.

Comment: Any reason you cannot make your elapsed function simply do `Task.Run(() => DoWork())` that way the work happens in the background?

Comment: The actions you want to start really should run on their own threads/backgroundworker etc.. then the timer can schedule new ones independently. Btw, I see no reason why the List<times&action tuples> should be immutable. But a setter would have to re-start the timer according to the new times. And for a scheme of sparsely ticking timers see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092955/timer-once-a-minute-on-the-minute/37092994?s=4|1.8662#37092994)

Comment: As you know the array before starting you can dymanically change the timer interval  so it's fires on the next start time.

Comment: @Bob yes, I can change interval. But it's still possible to miss som interval if action is too long.

Comment: @TaW Yes, I thought about it. So in case of TRUE condition I need to run action in separate thread/task to avoid influence of executing Action on next timer check.

Comment: Yes. A System.Windows.Forms.Timer  object runs on the UI thread, so the jobs it starts should not block the UI thread, either by being short or by running in a separate thread. They can always pass in their results with an Invoke call.. - Note that there are other TImers, though..

Answer (score 0):

Option 3: Calculate how long (from now) until each item in the array - and set a timer for each interval. There is no "minute polling" so no chance of missing a time.

Option 4: Use one of the many pre-canned "Scheduler" libraries.